# Flowscope and get request

Tags: jsf-2.2

I'm experimenting the new "flow" functionality.
It seems very promising because it lets you have a managed bean which spans across multiple related views.

Unfortunately it works only with post requests.

Is there a way to enter a flow using a **get request** ? All the few example I found use a starting form outside of the flow. I would like to enter a flow clicking on an item inside a Primefaces menubar and, as far as I know, I can only put a link there...

Suppose then that a user bookmarks a page in the middle of a flow. If a get request for a view in the middle of a flow is sent and the flow is no more active (or flow information are removed from the querystring parameters) the server responds with a bad error page. In such cases is it possible to be redirected to the **first node of the flow** ?

Navigating through the view nodes of a flow I can see a special parameter in the querystring which most likely is an ID. Is it possible to hide that detail ?

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just if the flow is named flow1, you can write something like:

```
<h:link value="Enter Flow" outcome="flow1"/>
```

That's it.

About the navigation, there is nothing that handles that in a explicit way, but you can override FlowHandler implementation, specifically the method clientWindowTransition(...) and check in that part if the flow is active and do what's necessary. To get out from a flow under a navigation outside of the flow you can override ViewHandler.createView(...) method and add the transition.

The flow state is bound to a client window id, which is what you are seeing as a query param. This detail is necessary because it provides an state that persist across navigation, but that is not as large as session state, which comprise multiple windows or tabs.

I recommend to use [Apache MyFaces JSF 2.2 Implementation](http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/index.html) because the solution there has taken into account cases like multiple nested flows. It works pretty well. Take a look at this JSF 2.2 examples from [Michael Kurz JSF Live blog on Github](https://github.com/jsflive/jsf22-examples), that could be helpful.